# Проблема с выводом посредством Foreach PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Имеется массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 120
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 168
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 173
        )
        
        .....
)
```

прохожу по массиву посредством foreach:

```
    foreach($b as $key => $value){
//тут еще будет запрос в бд для получения данных по каждому product_id ($value)
        $get = array($key => $value);
        print_r($get);
    }
```

получаю на вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 120
        )

)

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 168
        )

)

Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 173
        )

)
```

как привести вывод в порядок Array( Array 1, Array 2 ...., а не по отдельности
необходимо для того чтобы для каждого товара получить значение views (views: 1), затем суммировать количество views:1

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Что надо в итоге ?

Comment: Количество записей в таблице views со статусом status = 1, если 10 записей имеет такой статус, то итог будет: Количесто 10

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = [0=>['product_id'=>120],1=>['product_id'=>168],2=>['product_id'=>173]];
foreach($a as $key => $value){
    $a[$key]=$value['product_id'];
}
print_r($a);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Если использовать **[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php)** вот так:

```
$productIds = array_column($array, 'product_id');
```

то можно получить массив с идентификаторами `[120, 168, 173]`. Дальше его можно подставить в запрос в `SELECT...FROM....WHERE id IN (ВОТ СЮДА)`

Comment: Ключи первичного массива потеряем(правда не уверен что они нужны, вопрос не описывает желаемого поведения :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а зачем они нужны для вставки или выборки из БД?

Comment: Для какой то причины автор их получал :) иначе можно писать сокращенной записью ```foreach($a as $value)``` тем более там упоминалась обработка запросами по каждой записи отдельно :)

ps я не отрицаю что ваш способ лучше при пакетной обработке, и меньше мороки с ручным описанием :) возможно это именно то что нужно автору, просто уточнил что будут потеряны ключи первичного массива, и если это критично - можно руками сделать всю работу :)

Comment: ключи не важны, нужно PRODUCT_ID пройтись по бд

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня логика такая: имеется массив с product_id, далее необходимо посредством product_id = id, пройтись по БД (другая таблица) в данной таблице есть product_id и status как совершить такой запрос посредством array_column,

Comment: @Lexa я написал в ответе... итоговый запрос должен быть таким `SELECT...FROM....WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

Comment: @Lexa т.е. чтобы это сделать нужен будет ещё implode......но если делать по уму, то надо будет использвовать mysqli или pdo и тогда никакие implode не понадобятся и можно будет подавать на вход в функцию сам массив с идентификаторами